# ASP.NET Identity schema changes issue when using Code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity-2

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` code first app I had first added `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to builtin `ApplicationUser.cs`. After running `add-migration` and `update-database` commands in `PM console` it had added corresponding columns of type `nvarchar(max)` in SQL Server 2012 database. I then added data annotations `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(5)")]` to these two properties along with adding another property `FullName` with same data annotation. I then ran `add-migration` and `update-database` commands again but this time only the `FullName` column was added to the table (with varchar(15) as expected); but the lengths of the other two columns did not change and remained nvarchar(max). When I ran the above two commands again the migration file was empty - that means it did not detect any further changes. **Question**: How can I have the column lengths of the other two columns change via migration commands?

**ApplicationUser.cs** [With initial change]

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser.cs** [With second change after add-migration and update-database was ran on the first change above]

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
    public string FullName{ get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should actually use `[MaxLength(15)]` instead of `[Column( ...)]`, because max length should be translated by most provides to varchar or nvarchar (or other database specific names for it), where when using `ColumnAttribute`, you hardcode yourself against a specific database (i.e. mysql, mssql etc)

Comment: [MaxLength(15)] should do the trick. Btw. I've had some strange issues with "Add-Migration" too. Missing fields, incorrect length and so on in my migrations. Even when I deleted my migration! Restarting MSVC helped. :D I'm using MSVC 2017.